# How to reference bundle path in config.yml in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In order to make bundle work on its own i would like to call my class (Paypal) from a current bundle path. What is the way to do it?

```
#MyBundle/Resources/Config/config.yml
parameters:
    paypal.class:      **DontKnowWhatToPutHere**/Services/Paypal
    paypal.argument: exampleParam

services:
    paypal:
        class:        %paypal.class%
        arguments:    [%paypal.env%]
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the namespaced class name...

```
FooVendor\BarBundle\Services\Paypal
```